# How to convert an array of objects to a map

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an array like below:

```
var arr = [ 
  {
    "id" :"1",
    "name" : "xyz"
  },
  {
    "id" :"2",
    "name" : "abc"
  },
  {
    "id" :"2",
    "name" : "cde"
  }
]
```

I want to convert it into following format:

```
{
  '2' : ['abc','cde'],
  '1' : 'xyz'
}
```

How can I do this? Is there some special method for this in angular js?

Comment: Try adding lodash to your project and then `_.groupBy(arr, 'id')`

Comment: angular is a *framework*, not a *language*.  you would be doing this *in JavaScript*, the way you would do it even if angular wasn't being used.

Answer (score 2):

iterate over the entire arr and for each object keep adding name to a new object based on id.

```js
var arr = [ 
{
  "id" :"1",
  "name" : "xyz"
},
{
  "id" :"2",
  "name" : "abc"
},
{
  "id" :"2",
  "name" : "cde"
}
  ];

var obj ={};

arr.forEach(x => obj.hasOwnProperty(x.id) ? obj[x.id].push(x.name) : obj[x.id] = [x.name]);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.However  I am getting following exception when I i execute above code in my angular controller:                       


error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":41,"oldVal":40}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":42,"oldVal":41}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":43,"oldVal":42}],[{"msg":"fn: regularInterceptedExpression","newVal":44,"oldVal":43}],[{"msg":"fn:

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid globals by using reduce, hashing the values as you walk the array.

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "xyz"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "cde"
  }
];



let result = arr.reduce((hash, v) => (!hash[v.id] ? hash[v.id] = [v.name] : hash[v.id].push(v.name), hash), ({}))


console.log(result)
```